# Need advise on html/css coding

Tags: html, css

I know this is a simple question but I cant seem to get my head round it, can someone adivse me how I would arrange the images to be in a 3xgrid and/or fit in the big box?

this is the code - http://jsfiddle.net/kommandoss/YuRpU/21/

thank you

Comment: Please put a real question in your title/post.

Answer (score 3):

`float:left` or `display:inline-block`.

```
#deck>div{
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/YuRpU/24/

Comment: Yes: it needs to be placed on the div containing the img. (Also, had to +1 to kill your 666 score)

Answer (score 0):

Add float:left to the img style declaration

```
img{ cursor: pointer; float:left;}
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/YuRpU/22/

Answer (score 0):

`div` is a block element and so will take up an entire line by default.

All you have to do is make them display inline OR get rid of the extra ones

```
<div>
    <img src="" alt="" />
    <img src="" alt="" />
    <img src="" alt="" />
</div>
<div>
    <img src="" alt="" />
    <img src="" alt="" />
    <img src="" alt="" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to float the inner divs to make them wrap, have a look at http://jsfiddle.net/YuRpU/23/ .